# Git lfs: how to force user to update working copy before locking file

Tags: git, locking, conflict, git-lfs

We use `git-lfs` to manage our Repository which contains many binary files. When user trys to lock a file using `git-lfs`, there is no checking, whether the file in working copy has the same version or newer than in remote repository. When the file in remote repository has newer version than the working copy, it may lead to conflict.

Is there any way by `git-lfs` to force user to update their working copy first, before trying to lock file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a feature that Git LFS has.  A Git LFS server may operate completely independently from a standard Git server, and there isn't a standard way to determine whether a branch is up to date without cloning the entire repository.  As such, the Git LFS server can't implement this feature.